# How to check if a textbox starts with any letter

Tags: vba, visual-studio-2010

I'm trying to determine if the text in my textbox starts with any letter in the alphabet.

This is what I have so far:

```
Dim Text As String = SearchTextBox.text
If Text.StartsWith("A-Za-z") Then
    'Do something..
Else
```

Comment: How is what you have not working?

Comment: I want to check if it starts with any letter in the alphabet.

Comment: I repeat my question.

Comment: See below answer.  If isnumeric(Left(textBox.Text, 1)) = False Then

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the left function.

```
If Left(textBox.Text, 1) = "B" Then
   'Do something
End if
```

Or if you mean any letter

```
If isnumeric(Left(textBox.Text, 1)) = False Then
   'Do something
End if
```

To address the special characters. This will look for it to be A-Z or a-z.

```
If Asc(Left(TextBox1.Text, 1)) > 64 And Asc(Left(TextBox1.Text, 1)) < 91 Or Asc(Left(TextBox1.Text, 1)) > 96 And Asc(Left(TextBox1.Text, 1)) < 123 Then
     'Do something
end if
```

Comment: Just because it's not a number doesn't mean it's a letter. `!@#$%^&*()<>,./?;':"[]\{}|-=_+...`.

Comment: @Bond I have a regular expression that removes any thing that isn't a letter a number or a comma  `Dim Text As String = Regex.Replace(SearchTextBox.Text, "[^A-Za-z0-9,]+", "")
            Text = Text.Trim()`

Comment: @reggiecook You probably should have mentioned that, don't you think? Also, it could still start with a comma and not be numeric and not be a letter.

Comment: @Bond and reggie cook.  Good points. I have added an alternative method if special characters are a concern.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
If Text Like "[a-zA-Z]*" Then
```